# How JSP and servlet is executed without main function?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I wonder a normal java code will show main not found error if it is executed without the main function but how JSP and servlet is executed without the main function. can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because they are executed by the container, not as standalone applications.

Comment: can you give a link that explains about the container?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I agree with manoj.The JSP/Servlets are executed by Web Container.The basic definition of web container:-

`Web Container specifies a runtime environment for web components that includes security, concurrency, lifecycle management, transaction, deployment, and other services.`

Basically most Java Web Application Developers uses Tomcat as Web Container.

Article or A Simple Description about the web container can be found [here](http://www.service-architecture.com/application-servers/articles/j2ee_web_server_or_container.html).

Java gives some Web Containers to Download [Link](http://java.sun.com/webservices/containers/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

May be off topic but still can be helpful:

If we use `main()` method in Jsp/servlet the main() method will not execute throughout the life cycle.Generally JSP/Servlets executes under webcontainer only. Webcontainer executes JSP/servlet life cycle or callback methods only in order to execute JSP/Servlet.So throughout the life cycle of JSP/Servlet, the webcontainer will execute `init(ServletConfig),service(ServletRequest,ServletResponse),destroy()` methods.